# Error LNK2005: already defined in .obj

Tags: компоновщик, c++

Подскажите пожалуйста как побороть проблему?

```
error LNK2005: already defined in .obj
```

Уже не могу, что не пробовал и `#pragma once` и `#infndef` и вместе их, никак не могу победить данную проблему.
У меня есть файл в котором находятся функции сравнения и удаления для классов .. Это сделано, чтобы в другом классе просто объявить указатель на функцию и передавать туда нужную функцию. Но в этом файле нужно использовать объявленные классы. То есть перекрестное включение.
Вот файл

```
#ifndef HLPFUNC_H
#define HLPFUNC_H
#include "departament.h"
#include "brand.h"
#include "model.h"
#include "quality.h"
#include "parts.h"
#include "reptype.h"
#include "pointerArray.h"

void delDprt(void *delEl) {
        delete (departament*)(delEl);   
}
void delBrnd(void *delEl) {
        delete (brand*)(delEl); 
}
void delMdl(void *delEl) {
        delete (model*)(delEl);
}
void delRprTp(void *delEl) {
        delete (reptype*)(delEl);   
}
void delPrts(void *delEl) {
        delete (parts*)(delEl); 
}
void delQlty(void *delEl) {
        delete (quality*)(delEl);   
}
 int cmpDprt(void *p, string key) {
      if (((departament*)p)->name == key)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        if (((departament*)p)->name > key)
           {
            return 1;
        }
        else {return -1;}
    }
}
 int cmpBrand(void *p, string key) {
      if (((brand*)p)->name == key)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        if (((brand*)p)->name > key)
           {
            return 1;
        }
        else {return -1;}
    }
}
 int cmpModel(void *p, string key) {
         if (((model*)p)->name == key)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        if (((model*)p)->name > key)
           {
            return 1;
        }
        else {return -1;}
    }
}
 int cmpRprType(void *p, string key) {
          if (((reptype*)p)->name == key)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        if (((reptype*)p)->name > key)
           {
            return 1;
        }
        else {return -1;}
    }
}
 int cmpParts(void *p, string key) {
          if (((parts*)p)->name == key)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        if (((parts*)p)->name > key)
           {
            return 1;
        }
        else {return -1;}
    }
}
 int cmpQlty(void *p, string key) {
          if (((quality*)p)->qlt == key)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        if (((quality*)p)->qlt > key)
           {
            return 1;
        }
        else {return -1;}
    }
     }
#endif
```

Соответственно в каждом из классов нужно включить этот файл.
Пробовал разделять этот файл на отдельно заголовочный и сорцевый, включал в самый нижний класс этот файл и затем уже по иерархии вверх инклюдил уже нижний класс.
Ничего не помогает, то есть сами файлы компилируется в объектные файлы нормально, а вот уже линковка не проходит.
Помогите пожалуйста.
Не знаю что придумать даже ...

Answer (score 2):

Используйте forward declaration.

Foo.hpp:

```
class Bar;

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(Bar const& bar) { ... }
};
```

Bar.hpp:

```
class Foo;

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(Foo const& foo) { ... }
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "Foo.hpp"
#include "Bar.hpp"

int main()
{
    // делаем что-то с Foo и Bar
};
```

Comment: Не получается ничего. Немного не понял ,это работает только для классов ? Мне нужно связать обычный файл с функциями с классом и перекрестно .

Answer (score 2):

Уверен что за три года автор вопроса и сам разобрался что к чему, но всё же жаль оставлять вопрос без ответа.

Судя по

```
#ifndef HLPFUNC_H
#define HLPFUNC_H
```

все это находится в некоем hlpfunc.h, который в свою очередь включается в несколько *.cpp. Был бы .c/.cpp файл был один проблема бы не проявилась.

Вот в чём суть проблемы. Компилятор преобразует **каждый** .c/.cpp файл в .obj **независимо** при этом на прочие файлы он внимания не обращает - они также подключаются независимо (от соседнего .obj).

Как же туда попадают разные .h и .hpp? А просто - с помощью *`#include "..."`*. Причём, если не вдаваться в детали, это простая вставка текста из подключаемого файла в наш .c/.cpp файл. Вставка происходит рекурсивно и чтобы не добавлять дубликатов компилятор (с помощью препроцессора) следит за `#ifndef` и `#pragma once`. Поэтому внутри одного .obj не будет повторов реализаций. Но каждый .obj будет иметь свою копию hlpfunc.h и соответственно линковщик эти повторы найдёт и выдаст `error LNK2005`.

Как здесь всё исправить. Перенести реализацию функций в отдельный .cpp файл (не забыть добавить его к проекту :) ) а в заголовочном файле оставить только определения.

hlpfunc.h:

```
....
void delDprt(void *delEl);
void delBrnd(void *delEl);
....
```

hlpfunc.c:

```
#include "hlpfunc.h"
....
void delDprt(void *delEl) {
        delete (departament*)(delEl);   
}
void delBrnd(void *delEl) {
        delete (brand*)(delEl); 
}
....
```

Comment: Дополню, к этому отличному ответу, что иногда бывает и так, что некоторые программисты умудряются воткнуть в "хедер" не определение, а реализацию. Учитываю, что этот вопрос (с небольшими изменениями) я вижу за неделю уже третий раз, я не стал бы исключать и такого источника проблемы с линковкой.

Comment: Абсолютно согласен, @АлександрМуксимов . Я не слал расписывать как это можно использовать, но вот пример: мне довелось приводить в порядок один проект в котором компилировался только main.cpp, а все прочие *.cpp подключались к нему #include "...cpp". И это был рабочий проект!